# Spring Security ACL: NotFoundException from JDBCMutableAclService.createAcl

Tags: spring-security, spring-transactions

I've been working on this task for too long to abandon the idea of using Spring Security to achieve it, but I wish that the community will provide with some support that will help reduce the regret that I have for choosing Spring Security. Enough ranting and now let's get to the point.

I'm trying to create an ACL by using JDBCMutableAclService.createAcl as follows:

```
 public void addPermission(IWFArtifact securedObject, Sid recipient, Permission permission,
   Class clazz) {
  ObjectIdentity oid = new ObjectIdentityImpl(clazz.getCanonicalName(), securedObject.getId());
  this.addPermission(oid, recipient, permission);
 }

 @Override
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, readOnly = false)
 public void addPermission(ObjectIdentity oid, Sid recipient, Permission permission) {
  SpringSecurityUtils.assureThreadLocalAuthSet();

  MutableAcl acl;

  try {
   acl = this.mutableAclService.createAcl(oid);
  } catch (AlreadyExistsException e) {
   acl = (MutableAcl) this.mutableAclService.readAclById(oid);
  }
// try {
// acl = (MutableAcl) this.mutableAclService.readAclById(oid);
// } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
// acl = this.mutableAclService.createAcl(oid);
// }

  acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().length, permission, recipient, true);
  this.mutableAclService.updateAcl(acl);

 }
```

The call throws a NotFoundException from the line:

```
    // Retrieve the ACL via superclass (ensures cache registration, proper retrieval etc)
    Acl acl = readAclById(objectIdentity);
```

I believe this is caused by something related to Transactional, and that's why I have tested with many TransactionDefinition attributes. I have also doubted the annotation and tried with declarative transaction definition, but still with no luck.

One important point is that I have used the statement used to insert the oid in the database earlier in the method directly on the database and it worked, and also threw a unique constraint exception at me when it tried to insert it in the method.

I'm using Spring Security 2.0.8 and IceFaces 1.8 (which doesn't support spring 3.0 but definetely supprorts 2.0.x, specially when I keep caling `SpringSecurityUtils.assureThreadLocalAuthSet())`. My AppServer is Tomcat 6.0, and my DB Server is MySQL 6.0

I wish to get back a reply soon because I need to get this task off my way

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't formatted very well to understand on which line error is thrown.
Anyway a NotFoundException has to catched and create a new acl :

```
try {
    acl = (MutableAcl) mutableAclService.readAclById(oi);
}
catch (NotFoundException e) {
    acl = mutableAclService.createAcl(oi);
}
```